# How to determine is character is Chinese in c++?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, hex, utf

In python you can check a char 'c' in a condition for e.g if(c >= 0x4E00 and c <= 0x9FFF) ..and so on to determine if character is Chinese. How do we go about doing that in cpp? I have tried using (unsigned int)c and some ways to convert it to utf-8 first and try. Please suggest a way to compare a character's hex in c++.

Thanks!

Comment: `and some ways to convert it to utf-8 first` You mean it is not in unicode in first place? Then what encoding are you reading?

Comment: I am able to convert it to utf-8. When I print using cout << std::showbase << std::hex << int(c) << endl; I get value 0x3f. But the if condition of if(c >= 0x4E00 and c <= 0x9FFF) is not satisfied. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I am am able to convert it to utf-8"? How did you convert it? And what did you convert it from?

Comment: For string I am able to do   std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt<char16_t, char, std::mbstate_t>, char16_t> convert;

  std::u16string u16 = convert.from_bytes(text);
  std::string u8 = convert.to_bytes(u16);
  return u8.. I am not sure if that would help in recognizing a character. Any suggestions?

Comment: @user3116971 `0x3F` is `'?'`, which means data lost is occurring during your conversions (assuming the original character was not actually `'?'` to begin with).  Which usually means you are using the wrong locale for a conversion. To convert between a UTF-16 `std::u16string` and a UTF-8 `std::string`, you should be using `codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>`. But no matter what, a *single* `char` CANNOT contain a value greater than `0x7F` or `0xFF`, depending on whether your compiler implements `char` as signed or unsigned, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find UTF Character support in C++ (language or library), it supports normal and wide characters but no real UTF.

Maybe this can help you, as the unicode consortium itself has an open-sourced C/C++ Library which should help you to solve your conversion problem.
(http://site.icu-project.org/)

Of course, some leaner solutions can be found with the help of google easily

Comment: rici's answer below is cool, wasn't aware of that at least minimal support.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is in UTF-8 and you are using a UTF-8 locale, you can use [`std::mbrtoc32`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbrtoc32) to extract Unicode code points one at a time from the string. The example on the linked web page from cppreference.com shows how to do that.

If the character(s) have a different encoding, it's impossible to offer advice eithout knowing the encoding.

Comment: Thank you. Can you give a example of how that could be used and elaborate? For example if I have  char c = '本'?

Comment: I tried an example from https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/mbrtoc32.htm and get 
mbrtoc32() fails to convert: Illegal byte sequence

Comment: @user3116971: `char c = '本'` is not portable C++ because `本` is not in the basic character set. So I could only offer an opinion about it if you told me which compiler you were using and that compiler's documentation were freely available and complete. For the example you cite, again you would need to clarify what exactly you wrote, but I suspect it was not `char mbs[] = u8"本";`. Even that is not fully portable, although it oftens works. In portable code you should use `u8"\u672C"`.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult. The issue is that C++ does not require One True Encoding, although it is moving towards Unicode (a bit late IMHO). Python 3 was able to ditch the baggage of the past in a way neither C++ nor Java nor even EcmaScript can do. So if you are going to use those languages, particularly C and C++, you need to come to terms with the fact that a "character" and a `char` are radically different concepts, and a "character" is probably a more complicated concept than you might suspect.